# Access VPN Server located behind a firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall

I have been trying to understand how a VPN client can access a VPN server that is behind a firewall.

A VPN server has an interface on the intranet and an interface on DMZ, and the firewall has an interface on DMZ and another interface that is directly connected to the Internet.

In this case how does a client even know what address to connect to from within their VPN client, as the VPN server doesn't have an external IP address? Does the client actually connect to the Internet interface of the firewall, and traffic gets routed to the firewall DMZ interface, to the VPN server DMZ interface, to the VPN server intranet interface and onto the intranet?

*Can a firewall have an IP address?*

This is what I can imagine how it happens. But I can't confirm it as every posts and tutorials I can find say the clients connects to **VPN server** through a tunnel. Conceptually I understand the tunneling thing, but I just can't get my head around this.

Exactly what should a client connect to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VPN client establishes a tunnel to VPN server to access the private network. So, it is expected for the client to connect to VPN server just like any other service. If you find that VPN server does not have an external IP (public IP), its private IP can be NATed by firewall or edge router.

The firewall does the job of protecting the network from unauthorized access in addition to other tasks like routing and NATing. The firewall can have multiple IP addresses not just one: private or public according to the network setup.

Comment: So you indeed give out the external IP address of the firewall for clients who would treat it as the IP for the VPN server?

Comment: @JohnSmithSr.: Not necessarily. The public IP can be NATed to some private IP without being assigned to any server. The public IP can exist only in firewall or NAT device rules.

Comment: thanks. Let me see if I understand this correctly. The VPN server has an internal IP and an external IP, which, however, is not explicitly assigned to it and is what is given to clients. When clients try to connect to this server using this external IP, traffic goes to firewall first, and inside the firewall there is NAT happening mapping the external IP to  VPN server's internal IP?